# I keep getting The input data is not a complete block at random intervals C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, tcpclient

im writing code for a server and client p2p file shearing (for school) and i keep getting this error at random somr files that are like 9mb they go through but bigger files like 40mb it downloads the first like 11 mb and than trows me the error i also fragment the file into 1mb chunks encrypt and send it then recive decrypt and append to file

**server:**

```
namespace krizecKrozec
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace TicTacToeGame
    {
        public partial class ServerForm : Form
        {
            private TcpListener tcpListener;
            private TcpClient tcpClient;
            private NetworkStream networkStream;
            public string filepath;
            public byte[] key;


            // Fragment the file into 1MB pieces
            int chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB

            public ServerForm()
            {
                InitializeButtons();

                StartServer();
            }

            private void InitializeButtons()
            {

                Button button = new Button();
                button.Text = "file";
                button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 30);
                button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 65);
                button.Tag = "";
                button.Click += openFileButton_Click;
                Controls.Add(button);

                Button button2 = new Button();
                button2.Text = "send";
                button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 30);
                button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2 * 65, 65);
                button2.Tag = "";
                button2.Click += snedFIle;
                Controls.Add(button2);

                Button button3 = new Button();
                button3.Text = "Back";
                button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 30);
                button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 2 * 65);
                button3.Tag = "";
                  button3.Click += end;
                Controls.Add(button3);


            }

            private void StartServer()
            {
                tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
                try { tcpListener.Start(); }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("to nebo delovalo saj že obstaja sever na tem naslovu");
                }


                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

                        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                        
                        neke();
                        MessageBox.Show("Client connected!"+ System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(key));


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"Error accepting client: {ex.Message}");
                        this.Close();
                    }
                });
            }

            private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filepath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                }


            }
            private void end(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                tcpClient.Close();
                tcpListener.Stop();
                networkStream.Close();
                StartupForm s = new StartupForm();
                this.Hide();
               s.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
            private void snedFIle(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                sendtoClient();
            }
            public string getFileString()
            {
                string fname = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                string ftype = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
                long fsize = new FileInfo(filepath).Length;


                return fname + "," + ftype + "," + fsize;
            }
            public void neke()
            {
                using (var dh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
                {
                    dh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
                    dh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

                    byte[] publicKeyBytes = dh.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
                    networkStream.Write(publicKeyBytes, 0, publicKeyBytes.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Server: Public key sent to client.");

                    byte[] clientPublicKeyBytes = new byte[256];
                
                        networkStream.Read(clientPublicKeyBytes, 0, clientPublicKeyBytes.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("Server: Public key received from client.");
                    
                    CngKey clientPublicKey = CngKey.Import(clientPublicKeyBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
                    byte[] sharedSecret = dh.DeriveKeyMaterial(clientPublicKey);
                    Console.WriteLine("Server: Shared secret computed.");
                    key = sharedSecret;
                }
            }
            private void sendtoClient()
            {

                if (filepath != null)

                    {byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
                    int totalChunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fileBytes.Length / chunkSize);
                    byte[] fileInfoBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(getFileString()+","+totalChunks+",");
                   networkStream.Write(fileInfoBytes, 0, fileInfoBytes.Length);

                    
                    using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
                    {
                        aes.KeySize = 256;
                        aes.Key = key;
                        aes.BlockSize = 128;
                        
                        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                       

                        for (int chunkIndex = 0; chunkIndex < totalChunks; chunkIndex++)
                        {
                            aes.GenerateIV();
                            byte[] iv = aes.IV;
                            // Extract a chunk of the file
                            int startOffset = chunkIndex * chunkSize;
                            int remainingBytes = Math.Min(chunkSize, fileBytes.Length - startOffset);
                            byte[] chunk = new byte[remainingBytes];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(fileBytes, startOffset, chunk, 0, remainingBytes);

                            // Encrypt the chunk using shared secret

                            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
                            using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
                            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                cryptoStream.Write(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
                                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                                byte[] encryptedChunk = encryptedStream.ToArray();

                                // Send the encrypted chunk to the client
                                networkStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

                                networkStream.Write(encryptedChunk, 0, encryptedChunk.Length);
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }

  
            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**and this is the client**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace krizecKrozec
{   
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Configuration;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
   


        namespace TicTacToeGame
    {
        public partial class ClientForm : Form
        {
            private TcpClient tcpClient;
            private NetworkStream networkStream;
            public string filepath;
            public byte[] key;


            private void end(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                tcpClient.Close();
                networkStream.Close();
                StartupForm s = new StartupForm();
                this.Hide();
                s.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
            public ClientForm()
            {
                InitializeButtons();
                ConnectToServer();
            }
            private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 
                 FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filepath = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
                    MessageBox.Show(filepath);
                }


            }
            private void recive(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Receive file information from the server
                byte[] fileInfoBytes = new byte[256]; // Adjust size based on your data
                int bytesReadFileInfo = networkStream.Read(fileInfoBytes, 0, fileInfoBytes.Length);
                string fileInfo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileInfoBytes, 0, bytesReadFileInfo);
              
                // Extract file information
                string[]fstring=fileInfo.Split(',');
                string fname = fstring[0];
                string ftype = fstring[1];
                string fsize = fstring[2];
                int ccount = Int32.Parse( fstring[3]);



               MessageBox.Show($"Client: File information received - Name: {fname}, Type: {ftype}, Size: {fsize} bytes, fragments: {ccount}");
                filepath +="/"+ fname ;
                // Use shared secret to derive an encryption key
                using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.Key = key;
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                    
                    
                    aes.IV = new byte[16];
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

                    // Receive and decrypt each encrypted chunk
                    for (int chunkIndex = 0; chunkIndex < ccount; chunkIndex++)
                    {
                        // Receive encrypted chunk from the server
                        // Adjust size based on your data
                        networkStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
                        aes.IV = iv;
                        byte[] encryptedChunk = new byte[1024*1024];
                        int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(encryptedChunk, 0, encryptedChunk.Length);
                        
                        // Decrypt the chunk using shared secret
                        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
                        using (MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(decryptedStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(encryptedChunk, 0, bytesRead);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            byte[] decryptedChunk = decryptedStream.ToArray();

                            // Append the decrypted chunk to the file
                            AppendAllBytes(filepath, decryptedChunk);

                            Console.WriteLine($"Client: Decrypted chunk {chunkIndex + 1} received.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                //tcpClient.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Client: Connection closed.");
            }

        
                    
                
            
   

            public static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Use FileMode.Append to open the file and seek to the end for writing.
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, (FileShare)FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    // Handle or log the exception.
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error appending bytes to file: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }

        

            public void neke()
            {
                byte[] serverPublicKeyBytes = new byte[256]; // Assuming key size of 256 bytes
                networkStream.Read(serverPublicKeyBytes, 0, serverPublicKeyBytes.Length);
                CngKey serverPublicKey = CngKey.Import(serverPublicKeyBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
                Console.WriteLine("Client: Public key received from server.");

                // Generate Diffie-Hellman parameters
                using (var dh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
                {
                    dh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
                    dh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

                    // Send public key to the server
                    byte[] publicKeyBytes = dh.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
                    networkStream.Write(publicKeyBytes, 0, publicKeyBytes.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client: Public key sent to server.");

                    // Perform key exchange
                    byte[] sharedSecret = dh.DeriveKeyMaterial(serverPublicKey);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client: Shared secret computed.");
                    key = sharedSecret;

                }
            }


            private void InitializeButtons()
            {

                Button button = new Button();
                button.Text = "file";
                button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 30);
                button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 65);
                button.Tag = "";
                button.Click += openFileButton_Click;
                Controls.Add(button);

                Button button2 = new Button();
                button2.Text = "recive";
                button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 30);
                button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2 * 65, 65);
                button2.Tag = "";
                button2.Click += recive;
                Controls.Add(button2);

                Button button3 = new Button();
                button3.Text = "Back";
                button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 30);
                button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 2 * 65);
                button3.Tag = "";
                  button3.Click += end;
                Controls.Add(button3);

            }

            private void ConnectToServer()
            {
                tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 8080);

                        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                        neke();

                        MessageBox.Show("Connected to server!"+ System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(key));

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"Error connecting to server: {ex.Message}");

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i tryed diffrent paddings but insted i get padding error i tryed chatgpt and it keeps giving me code that dosnt fix anything

i tryed diffrent ways of sending diffrent aes mods and got same problem

Comment: _"trows me the error"_ - _what_ error?

Comment: it trows me The input data is not a complete block

Answer (score 2):

> int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(encryptedChunk, 0, encryptedChunk.Length);

You are apparently aware that you need to check the number of bytes actually read, but you do not seem to continue reading until you have received everything. Tcp is a stream oriented protocol, so you need to handle things like message framing, half open connections etc yourself. Your idea of "chunking" the data is flawed, reading data should be done in a loop so you continue reading until you have received all the data in the message. I would recommend reading [Stephen Clearys TCP FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) before attempting to do anything Tcp related.

If you want to get something *working* I would recommend using a higher level protocol that takes care of these things for you. I found MQTT fairly easy to use, But there are plenty of good alternatives to chose from. Many protocols will also have built in support for encryption.

Also note that for a true "p2p"-application you need some approach to handle firewalls. These will usually block any incoming connections. There are ways to handle this, but it will add additional complexity.

I would also recommend separating components and writing unit tests. Split your functionality into smaller components that does as little as possible, and write unit tests for these components so you know they actually works as intended. Writing a class that does many different things, like you have done, ensures that you will have a much harder time to debug anything.

To conclude, use existing methods, protocols, and libraries if you want any kind of usable system. If you are doing this for learning I think you need to drastically lower your ambition level. Just creating a system that reliably and consistently can move arbitrary sized messages from a client to a server using raw Tcp will be a fair amount of work. Adding in "p2p", encryption, etc will increase the complexity tremendously.